Selecting all cols in one SQL table based on a matching ID in another table and if TRUE then loop through all
I'm wanting query the officeSettings table with an officeID then where an App is 'TRUE' return the data from the matching appName in apppSettings table. Echo out the result then loop through all Apps.
I understand I need to use a JOIN but I'm getting lost with matching the officeID and then checking if TRUE.
officeSettings



officeID
App1
App2
App3




101010
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE


951751
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE


648299
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE



appSettings



appName
icon
URL
link1
url1
link2
url2




App1
img/app1.svg
#
#
#
#
#


App2
img/app2.svg
#
#
#
#
#


App3
img/app2.svg
#
#
#
#
#




What do you want as output?

You can use a query like this:
SELECT aps.*
FROM officeSettings ofs
JOIN appSettings aps ON
    (ofs.App1 = 'TRUE' AND aps.appName = 'App1') OR
    (ofs.App2 = 'TRUE' AND aps.appName = 'App2') OR
    (ofs.App3 = 'TRUE' AND aps.appName = 'App3')
WHERE ofs.officeID = 648299;

Outputs:



appName
icon
URL
link1
url1
link2
url2




App2
img/app2.svg
#
#
#
#
#


App3
img/app2.svg
#
#
#
#
#



The problem with this approach is that to add another app you have to add another column to officeSettings and then add the additional join criteria to the query.
A better approach is to store the officeSettings as (officeID, appName) tuples:
officeApps



officeID
appName




101010
App1


101010
App2


951751
App1


648299
App2


648299
App3



Now the query does not need to know about the individual apps:
SELECT aps.*
FROM officeApps oa
JOIN appSettings aps ON oa.appName = aps.appName
WHERE oa.officeID = 648299;

Still outputs:



appName
icon
URL
link1
url1
link2
url2




App2
img/app2.svg
#
#
#
#
#


App3
img/app2.svg
#
#
#
#
#




Legend thank you. Your solution is perfect as I would need to add/remove apps.
